# Ajax.ActionLink in MVC3 not working

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-ajax, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing an Asp.net MVC3 website from **VS2012RC**. I'm trying to create a partial view to the website using Ajax Actionlink. But it is not working. After trying everything I know with my team and a lot of searching, I then tried it on a TestProject. To my further depression that is also not working. I have tried to work around this for a long time and now I'm calling SO.

This is how I created my test project. Please let me know whether I am making a mistake or this is a fault in my machine.

1. I have created an MVC3 empty Project with html5 semantic markup and with the view engine of Razor.
2. Then I added a Home controller to my project and created a view for View() action.
3. Then I created another action TestAjax().
4. Then I Created a partial view in the **Home Folder in Views
   Folder**.

This is my Index view:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("This is a test ajax","testAjax",new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId =                                       "TestAjax" ,HttpMethod ="GET",InsertionMode =InsertionMode.InsertAfter})

    </div>

    <div id ="TestAjax">
    </div>
```

Partial View is :

```
<h1>Testing testing testing testing</h1>
```

Now what I expect is that when I click the link the header hast to appear below the link in the TestAjax division. But what actually happens is in home page the link appears. When I click the link, it will go to the "/Home/testAjax" and display only the partial view. There is no partial view.

Can you tell me what is the wrong with this procedure.

EDIT:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript">         </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type = "text/javascript"> </script>  
</head>
```

When I check the resources in the webpage of the view Index():

```
<a href="/Home/TestAjax" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.insertAfter, httpMethod: 'GET', updateTargetId: 'TestAjax' });">This is a test ajax</a>
```

Comment: What happens when you click on the link? Have you referenced the `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"` js file in your layout/view? Because this js file is required for the `Ajax.ActionLink` and `Ajax.BeginForm` to work correctly.

Comment: Ah Sorry!!! It will show only the partial view. My bad I'lledite the question.

Comment: Do I have to insert this reference to both of the view(Index, TestAjax)?

Comment: No, only in your main view Index or into the `_Layout.cshtml` but you should not put in the partial.

Comment: I added the `<script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` to the `_Layout.cshtml` But there is this `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`there. And I added `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` to the Index View but the result is the same. :(

Comment: Con you update your question how is the stuff between the `<head></head>` looks like now in your `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: Are you sure that `jquery-1.6.2.min.js` exists?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  Well How can I test that this exists.

Comment: You look in your `Scripts` folder. Or even better in the Net tab of FireBug. If it doesn't you will see 404 response code from the server for it.

Comment: Why are you creating MVC3 project, and not MVC4 which is latest version? Using VS2012RC I would think you are keen on using "the latest technology"..?

Comment: You should also make sure that you have this line `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` in your web.config  `appSettings` section.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I lokked it on the script folder and its there. I ll try FireBug as well.

Comment: Your `UpdateTargetId` is `Testajax`, but the Id on the page is `TestAjax`.

Comment: @Martin  sorry about that. I added some meaningful words to the code. Sorry for the inconvenience. Its not the problem. Its still there :(

Comment: Can you see javascript errors in your FireBug console?

Comment: I have installed FireBug Lite in my Crome. In the Script tab of the showed `Access to restricted URI denied.` when I clicked the link.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov thanks for the suggestion for using FireBug.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Inspect is selected as "Crome.js"

Comment: The `onclick` attribute generated on your link is very strange and shouldn't be there. It's as if you hadn't the following in your web.config: `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>` although you said you have it, so I don't know why is it there. You are not using unobtrusive jquery AJAX (which is the default normally in ASP.NET MVC 3) but the obsolete now Microsoft js.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Please continue this is chat.

Comment: @Diode Please continue this in chat.

Comment: @Diode, what is the output if you put the following in your Razor view: `@ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled`? Is it `True` or `False`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks for helping me through all these times. Its true. I thought this was locked and left :(. I am hoping to redo the project in VS 2010. and add the code there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referenced the `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` js file was not in my layout/view. Since I was not familiarized with ajax. So, people who are new to ajax in MVC and came here by Googling, First check this reference mentioned above is in your layout/view.